# Does Android have something like iOS method swizzling (for PhoneGap plugin initialization)?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, method-swizzling

I am writing some PhoneGap plugins for both iOS and Android that wrap third-party native SDKs. In the case of iOS, I was able to use swizzling to add behavior to the `AppDelegate` for the purpose of initializing these libraries.

Now I need to do the same for Android and I'm now sure how to go about it. As an example, I am working with the [AppsFlyer](http://www.appsflyer.com) SDK now and this is how the docs say to initialize:

---

[image: AppsFlyer Android SDK Documentation]

---

Is there a technique for doing something like this in a PhoneGap plugin? I need to be able to build the project from scratch without the Android Studio project itself being under source control.

Thanks!

Comment: Today you have Appsflyer cordova plugin:  https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/PhoneGap